# How to get bluetooth working on Macbook Pro 6.2

Tags: 10.10, bluetooth, macbook-pro

Has anyone figured out how to get bluetooth working on a Macbook Pro 6,2 under Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: In 12.04, Bluetooth works out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get bluetooth support by install the btusb-dkms module from the [Mactel PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa):

To add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mactel-support && sudo apt-get update
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install btusb-dkms
```

- [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/660729)
- Instructions for how to use PPAs: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)